# Making an atom of a subscription requires derefing twice. Problem only occurs when using defonce

Tags: clojurescript, reagent, re-frame

When I use `def` to save an atom, it works as expected. But when I use `defonce`, I have to deref twice: `@@my-state`. I want to use `defonce` because I want state preserved during reloads.

This works as expected

```
(def my-state (reagent/atom (re-frame/subscribe [::subs/photos])))
```

This requires two derefs to access the values

```
(defonce my-state (reagent/atom (re-frame/subscribe [::subs/photos])))
```

Subscription code

```
(re-frame/reg-sub
  ::photos
  (fn [db [_]]
    (:photos db)))
```

Answer (score 1):

> I want to use `defonce` because I want state preserved during reloads.

Then just don't use Reagent's atoms, use re-frame's subscriptions instead. They derive their values from re-frame's `app-db` which is itself defined with `defonce`.